# How to reduce a List[Key, List[Name, Value]] in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is the structure of my models

```
package object summary {
  case class NameValuePair(name: String, value: Long)

  case class Result(key: String, pairs: List[NameValuePair])

  case class Data(data: List[Result])
}
```

The data will be like

```
[
Result("Paris", List[NameValuePair("apples",10),NameValuePair("oranges",20),NameValuePair("peaches",30)]),
Result("Paris", List[NameValuePair("apples",20),NameValuePair("oranges",30),NameValuePair("peaches",40)]),
Result("NY", List[NameValuePair("apples",20),NameValuePair("oranges",30),NameValuePair("peaches",40)]),
Result("NY", List[NameValuePair("apples",40),NameValuePair("oranges",30),NameValuePair("peaches",10)]),
Result("London", List[NameValuePair("apples",20),NameValuePair("oranges",30),NameValuePair("peaches",40)])
]
```

I want the output like below

```
[
("Paris", [("apples", 30),("oranges", 50),("peaches",70)]),
("NY", [("apples", 60),("oranges", 60),("peaches",50)]),
("London", [("apples", 20),("oranges", 30),("peaches",40)])
]
```

I want to find the sum of fruit counts based on cities. How to do this with spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using spark RDDs like so :

I recreated your data to create an RDD :

```
val data_test =
List(Result("Paris", List( new NameValuePair("apples",10),new NameValuePair("oranges",20), new NameValuePair("peaches",30))),
Result("Paris", List( new NameValuePair("apples",20), new NameValuePair("oranges",30),new NameValuePair("peaches",40))),
Result("NY", List(new NameValuePair("apples",20),new NameValuePair("oranges",30), new NameValuePair("peaches",40))),
Result("NY", List(new NameValuePair("apples",40), new NameValuePair("oranges",30), new NameValuePair("peaches",10))),
Result("London", List(new NameValuePair("apples",20),new NameValuePair("oranges",30),new NameValuePair("peaches",40))) )
```

Then I created the RDD from data_test and applied transformations to it, here is the code :

```
val rdd_data = sc.parallelize(data_test)
val rdd_1 = rdd_data.map(x => ((x.key,x.pairs(0).name),x.pairs(0).value))
val rdd_2 = rdd_data.map(x => ((x.key,x.pairs(1).name),x.pairs(1).value))
val rdd_3 = rdd_data.map(x => ((x.key,x.pairs(2).name),x.pairs(2).value))
val rdd_final = rdd_1.union(rdd_2).union(rdd_3)
val rdd_reduce = rdd_final.reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y)
val rdd_transformed = rdd_reduce.map(x=>(x._1._1,(x._1._2,x._2))).groupByKey().map(x=>(x._1,x._2.toList))
rdd_transformed.foreach(println)
```

The obtained result looks like such :

```
(NY,List((peaches,50), (apples,60), (oranges,60)))
(London,List((apples,20), (peaches,40), (oranges,30)))
(Paris,List((oranges,50), (peaches,70), (apples,30)))
```

[EDIT AFTER COMMENT] 
If the number of pairs varies you can define a function like so :

```
def func(res : Result): List[((String,String),Long)] = {
    var r = List[((String,String),Long)]()
    var i = List[NameValuePair]()
    for(i <- res.pairs){
        val tt : ((String,String),Long)= ((res.key,i.name),i.value)
        r = tt :: r
    }
    return r
}
```

Then you can directly skip to the line where I generate rdd_final above like so :

```
val rdd_final = rdd_data.flatMap(x=>func(x))
```

Then execute the other instructions the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But the nameValuePairs are not fixed to a length of 3. It is dynamic.

Comment: Hello, I updated my answer to be able to handle a dynamic number of nameValuePairs, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I would use dataframe group by function to do it. Like this:

```
import spark.implicits._
Seq(
  Result("Paris", List( new NameValuePair("apples",10),new NameValuePair("oranges",20), new NameValuePair("peaches",30))),
  Result("Paris", List( new NameValuePair("apples",20), new NameValuePair("oranges",30),new NameValuePair("peaches",40))),
  Result("NY", List(new NameValuePair("apples",20),new NameValuePair("oranges",30), new NameValuePair("peaches",40))),
  Result("NY", List(new NameValuePair("apples",40), new NameValuePair("oranges",30), new NameValuePair("peaches",10))),
  Result("London", List(new NameValuePair("apples",20),new NameValuePair("oranges",30),new NameValuePair("peaches",40)))
).flatMap(row => {
  val city = row.key
  val fruits = row.pairs
  fruits.map(f => {
    val fruitName = f.name
    val v = f.value
    (city, fruitName, v)
  })
}).toDF("city", "fruit", "value")
  .groupBy("city").sum().show()
//The result would be:
+------+----------+
|  city|sum(value)|
+------+----------+
|London|        90|
| Paris|       150|
|    NY|       170|
+------+----------+
```